# TCP Scanner Python MultiThreaded

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I'm trying to build a small tcp scanner for a netmask.

The code is as follow:

```
import socket,sys,re,struct
from socket import *


host = sys.argv[1]

def RunScanner(host):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,80))
    s.settimeout(0.1)  
    String = "GET / HTTP/1.0"
    s.send(String)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
       print "host: %s have port 80 open"%(host)

Slash = re.search("/", str(host))

if Slash :
   netR,_,Wholemask = host.partition('/')
   Wholemask = int(Wholemask)
   netR = struct.unpack("!L",inet_aton(netR))[0]
   for host in (inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!L", netR+n)) for n in range(0, 1<<32-Wholemask)):
      try:
         print "Doing host",host
         RunScanner(host)
      except:
         pass
else:
   RunScanner(host)
```

To launch : python script.py 10.50.23.0/24

The problem I'm having is that even with a ridiculous low settimeout value set, it takes ages to cover the 255 ip addresses since most of them are not assigned to a machine.

How can i make a way faster scanner that wont get stuck if the port is close.MultiThreading ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use nmap. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the weel. Simply want to fingerprint some host very quickly.

Comment: What about I open 255 connections at the same time ?
Would that be correct ?

Comment: That's exactly what nmap does.

Comment: This post is about multi-threading 255 TCP connections, not python script vs nmap.

Comment: Well, you don't need to use threads for multiple connections. You can use a more efficient reactor model using select or poll. But your protocol is also wrong. In fact there are too many things wrong with this code I see here. So, to achieve your ultimate goal, just use nmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something I was doing in the past with threads. It should be super easy to change it with your input:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

def scan(d):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(0.1)
    port = 80  # port number is a number, not string
    try:
        address = '192.168.0.' + str(d)
        s.connect((address, port)) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print("something's wrong with %s:%d. Exception is %s" % (address, port, e))
    finally:
        s.close()

pool = ThreadPool() 

d = range(1, 255)
pool.map(scan, d)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```